# regexp, extract matches as multi array

Tags: regex, perl

problem:

```
$val1="alecosja niewiemcosja hehehcosja lelele ojejcosja ktoscosktos coskurw";
#list context:
@myarray=$val1=~m/([eh])cos(ja|kt|ku)/g;
```

`@myarray` will hold substrings from parenthesis

result `print "$_\n" (foreach (@myarray))`:

```
e \n ja \n h \n ja
```

is there any way for such solution:

```
$myarray[0][0] - first whole match, 
$myarray[0][1] - first substring from first match, 
$myarray[0][2] - second substring from first match
$myarray[1][0] - seonds whole match, 
$myarray[1][1] - first substring from second match etc.
```

It's kind of PHP newbie thinking, but how can I handle such problems?

Comment: "Whole match" is represented by the  `$&` variable. First substring capture (first parenthesis) is `$1`, the second `$2` etc. A regex match with `/g` modifier in scalar context will iterate over the matches, e.g. `while ($val1 =~ m/.../)`.

Comment: yea I know about it, but my question is about having both facilities inside one instruction (maybe using multi-dim arrays). And It's also possible to put subpatterns into (:? and then whole matches will be caught into array (in list context).

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is an "instruction"? And why does it have to concern multi-dimensional arrays? This is simple, and making it difficult for no reason makes no sense.

Comment: trying to catch all whole patterns and add also all subpatters (variable count). I would like to translate robust preg_match_all from PHP into perl. Unfortunatelly I have just started with Perl and my lack of knowledge make difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, why make things difficult for yourself? Using a while loop will allow you to access the built-in variables directly for each match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $val = "alecosja niewiemcosja hehehcosja lelele ojejcosja ktoscosktos coskurw";
my @result;
while ($val =~ m/([eh])cos(ja|kt|ku)/g) {
    push @result, [ $&, $1, $2 ];          # save matches
}
print Dumper \@result;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'ecosja',
            'e',
            'ja'
          ],
          [
            'hcosja',
            'h',
            'ja'
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but this will get you 95% of the way:

```
  DB<1> $val1="alecosja niewiemcosja hehehcosja lelele ojejcosja ktoscosktos coskurw";

  DB<2> @myarray=$val1=~m/(([eh])cos(ja|kt|ku))/g

  DB<3> x @myarray
0  'ecosja'
1  'e'
2  'ja'
3  'hcosja'
4  'h'
5  'ja'
```

If you don't already know how, it would be extremely useful for you to learn how to use the Perl command-line debugger.

Comment: Adding another () on whole match was helpful. thanks.